# Python time complexity of assigning a slice to another list slice in different length

Tags: python, time-complexity, slice

Assume that I have two lists named `a` and `b`, and I want to assign slice `b[j:j+len2]` with len2 elements to slice `a[i:i+len1]` with len1 elements, what's the time complexity of this operation?

```
a[i:i+len1] = b[j:j+len2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `len1 == len2` then it's `O(len1)` because it's equivalent to the loop:

```
for n in range(len1):
    a[i+n] = b[j+n]
```

But if the lengths are different, the elements after the slice in `a` have to be shifted to open or close the space required for the `b` slice. And if the list is growing, it's possible that the entire list needs to be relocated to make room. This makes the worst-case complexity `O(len(a) + len2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this wiki entry](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list).

Slice assignment in general is considered to be O(k+n), although I believe CPython has some optimizations